# How to create alluvial diagrams for land use change analysis

Tags: qgis, land-cover, change-detection, land-use

I have two landuse change maps and I'd like to create some [alluvial diagrams](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=alluvial%20diagram&biw=1356&bih=894&tbm=isch&imgil=QPgt2ywptxL3GM%253A%253BkAXOPL_i8ksSkM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fdigitalsplashmedia.com%25252F2014%25252F06%25252Fvisualizing-categorical-data-as-flows-with-alluvial-diagrams%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QPgt2ywptxL3GM%253A%252CkAXOPL_i8ksSkM%252C_&usg=___grJ35RetmXWwTtAwiui4LVeoSc%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiqoYacj8LJAhXFlJAKHbVACdUQyjcIMA&ei=SnthVqrUDsWpwgS1gaWoDQ#imgrc=_&usg=___grJ35RetmXWwTtAwiui4LVeoSc%3D) to show change over time. This way I can tell what became what. Are there any tools in QGis or other GIS that can create such graph?

Comment: I ended up creating a cross tabulation between the two land use maps and exporting the table to R. There I used an Alluvial diagram package that I found in http://www.r-bloggers.com/alluvial-diagrams/

Comment: do you still have the code you used for the analysis. I find it a bit hard to get through the code on the website you linked.

Comment: I found this very helpful: https://r-charts.com/flow/ggalluvial/